# Error in HTML escaping with Jinja

Tags: python, html, regex, jinja2

I have the following regex that searches through text and prepends and appends HTML 'a' tags for the matched substring. It successfully does everything I want except when the HTML is escaped by using the 'safe' filter by Jinja. The regex is below:

```
re.sub('(^#\w*|(?<=\s)#\w*)', 
        r'<a href="{{ url_for(\'main.tag\', tagname=tag) }}">\1</a>', 
        'here is some #text with a #hashtag')
```

The above should come out `here is some #text with a #hashtag`

where '#text' and '#hashtag' are clickable links. However by using Jinja's 'safe' filter it comes out

```
"here is some "<a href="{{ url_for(\'main.tag\', tagname=tag) }}">#text</a>" with a "<a href="{{ url_for(\'main.tag\', tagname=tag) }}">#hashtag</a>
```

There are a few things to note:

- Unmatched substrings are being wrapped in quotations
- The html links should come out `<a href="/tag/hashtag">#hashtag<a>` not `<a href="{{ url_for(\'main.tag\', tagname=tag) }}">#hashtag</a>`

I'm confident it has to do with the string that is being processed by Jinja. I am not confident with how I am escaping specific characters in the string and passing it to Jinja to process.

Am I escaping the characters wrong? Thoughts? Thank you in advance.